# Text on button in HTML

Tags: html

I have following code in HTML:

http://pastebin.com/GfrE1Pkh

I want to add text to banner_button_1 and banner_button_2. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This code is horrible, but I'll assume that you can not edit the HTML and just want to change it via JS.

```
var bannerButton = document.getElementsByClassName('banner-button')[0];

var bannerButtonLinks = bannerButton.getElementsByTagName('a');

bannerButtonLinks [0].innerHTML += "text for banner_button_1";

bannerButtonLinks [1].innerHTML += "text for banner_button_2";
```